# Getting Current Page URL From Master Page with Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, master-pages, url-routing

I'm trying to be able to determine which page url the user is loading from the master page.

So far I've been able to use

```
this.Request.RawUrl
```

to get the path of the page itself, which works fine for most cases.

However in this particular website, we use a lot of complicated routing, so something like (say)

/Product/5/2/Purchase

might redirect to /Purchase.aspx?ID=5Type=2

of which I'd want the actual aspx file path.

I've also tried `this.Request.PhysicalPath`, but that doesn't give the route and basically just appends the path the user requested to the virtual directory.

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

An asp.net Page treats a master page as just another control.

So if you want to get the page, you can always use the `Page` property provided by the [`MasterPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Sorry I explained badly. I want the URL of the page the user is trying to load, not a reference to the Page itself. (I updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

I used this and worked :

```
Page.ToString().Replace("ASP.","").Replace("_",".")
```

Comment: This copy of this answer is actually wrong. It does not give what the OP wants here.